# Pagination function for gallery, and single view - How to get NEXT and PREV? (DETAILED)

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, pagination

I would like to see if there is a more efficient way to get the previous and next buttons for my pagination script.  It is setup to accept one argument `(int)` that sets the `$posts_per_page`.  When on gallery view, images are listed and linked to with pretty permalinks, ex. `site.com/membername/3483/` - with the (int) being the picture ID.

Now, because it is on a SINGLE view page, it only shows one image.  I would like to have next and previous buttons, that make use of the IDs, rather than the `?page=` query variable.  So, I am in need of a way to find the `array position` in the same function.

Currently, I am making use of THREE functions to accomplish my goals.  They are:

**ONE:** `function photo_gallery_paginated($posts_per_page)`

This function takes the $posts_per_page, and returns the paged gallery. It is called like this on the gallery page;

```
$allImages = (array)query_user_uploads('all');

$pg = (get_query_var('pg')) ? get_query_var('pg') : 1;
$prev = $pg -1;
$next = $pg +1;
```

The links are then built by manually adding the picture ID into the URL.

```
<a class="thumbnail view-photo" href="../photo-single/<?php echo $image->attachment_id; ?>"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $image->attachment_id  ); ?>"></a>
```

---

**TWO:**  `function query_user_uploads($attr, $attachID = null)`

This function queries the same exact data that function ONE queries. It is used with function three below.  It is placed on the gallery single page(when you click an image from function one, this is loaded in the single page), and is called like this;

```
$attachmentID = get_query_var('photo-single');
$attachmentData = query_user_uploads('single', $attachmentID);
```

---

**THREE:**

This is the function used to display the gallery single pagination from left to right.  The idea is once on a gallery single page, you can click next and previous to browse the users images.

```
function locate_buttons($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val->ID === $id) {
          $current = $key;
           if (isset($array[$current+1]))
               $next = $array[$key+1];
            else
               $next = $array[$key];

           if (isset($array[$current-1]))
               $prev = $array[$key-1];
            else
               $prev = $array[$key];

           $button['next'] = $next;
           $button['prev'] = $prev;
           $button['current'] = $array[$key];
           return $button;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

This is how it is called (at the bottom of the page);

```
$buttonsBuild = locate_buttons($attachmentID, query_user_uploads('all'));

$prev = $buttonsBuild['prev']->ID;
$next = $buttonsBuild['next']->ID;
```

This returns the next, and previous ID numbers for the images.  But this is obviously extremely inefficient, and calls the same DB data three times.  Before you bite my head off, this is my first time writing a pagination function- and YES I am aware I can use `?ID=3483&offset=3` - and I have used that.  But I want the ID to be rewritten in the URL for bookmarking purposes.

So, to those who read this far, YES i will choose you as best answer if you can help me simplify this. Thank you in advance, and I will be here to answer any clarification questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won't you just create a simple .htaccess rule while using `?ID=3483&offset=3`.

(can't comment sorry, some people took my reps)

Comment: No problem man, I could do that but it still leaves the issue of how to get the NEXT id for the single page.  When I do that, it will just change the last query.  So every image appears to have the same ID, and only the offset changes.

Comment: @GregL Make PHP behave like it's on the next image in a simulated area and get the ID of the next image. I don't how to do it, sorry. But as far as i can see it's possible with your functions.